# HTML Text Writer outside of System.Web.UI

Tags: asp.net, .net

Do you know of an HTML Text Writer that is outside of `System.Web.UI`?

I'd like to use it from within a console application.

Comment: Go through this URL, It may help You... :)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420555/alternatives-to-htmltextwriter-in-a-system-web-ui-control

Answer (score 0):

You can just reference the System.Web assembly in the console application. Right- click on the references in solution explorer and add it.

Comment: I know that. I was asking if there was another one available from outside of that assembly.

Comment: Ok, added answer if the problem was to use it within an console application.